# Image is not displayed when uploading to Twitter on my website

Tags: php, twitter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5M6S.png)

I add meta tag of twitter card to index file but don`t show image again

```php
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@example">
<meta name="twitter:title" content='<?PHP echo strip_tags(html_entity_decode(substr($title_str, 0, 69), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')); ?>'>
<meta name="twitter:description" content='<?PHP echo strip_tags(html_entity_decode(substr($content_str, 0, 199), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')); ?>'>
<meta name="twitter:image" content="<?PHP echo $ogimage_url; ?>">
```

Comment: have you taken a look at the source code the twitter bot sees? (i.e. the output of your php code)

Comment: How can I look after her?

Comment: I note that some pictures are visible